# probability for the product of two random numbers (within 0 to 1) is larger than 1/2

Tags: probability

Random real numbers uniformly distributed over the interval from 0 to 1. What is the probability that the product of two numbers from a random number is larger than 1/2?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to M.SE! Can you please share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried and what's giving you difficulty? This will help people write a response that addresses your question.

Comment: I feel like the problem for me is, I don't know where to start. So far, I know that a (any number) * b (any number less than .5) will be less than 1/2, so I have Pr(i1) = 100/100 * 50/100, Pr(i2) = 99/100 * 51/100, Pr(i3) = 98/100 * 52/100 ...
Here's where I'm stuck, how do I combine these probabilities and how to apply into larger intervals instead of 100 (that I randomly picked.)

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large 1 - {1 \over 2}\,\ln\left(2\right)}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin It's $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$ actually. You need to subtract the area to the left of the $y=\frac{1}{2x}$ curve.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: In effect you’re choosing a random point $\langle x,y\rangle\in[0,1]\times[0,1]$, where the distribution is uniform. The graph of the function $xy=\frac12$ divides the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ into two parts in a relevant way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  for problems like this, it often helps to think of the unit square.  Each random real is on one axis.  What fraction of the area satisfies the requirement?